# APPLITOOLS_API_KEY env variable is missing

Tags: cypress, applitools

APPLITOOLS_API_KEY env variable is missing. It is required to define this variable for Applitools visual tests to run successfully.

[Please see the error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdYU0.png)

Comment: Are you using this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@applitools/eyes-cypress

Comment: yes, getting the error but.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to prevent this.

1. Pass the env variable using the CLI like:

```js
export APPLITOOLS_API_KEY=<your_key> npx cypress open
```

2. Create a file in your project root `applitools.config.js` and mention your api key like:

```js
module.exports = {
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  // ...
}
```

In case you don't have any API key, you can refer this [article](https://applitools.com/docs/topics/overview/obtain-api-key.html).

Comment: Couldn't they also set the variable in a `.env` file?

Comment: That is a good question actually, the OP can try that as well. I followed the plugins page and this is how they are doing it - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@applitools/eyes-cypress

Comment: Yep. I think I default to using a `.env` file and adding that file to the `.gitignore`, since then I don't have to worry about keeping a secret in code (option 2) or any terminal _weirdness_ (potentially option 1). Cheers :D